# Determining if a squence is true

Tags: java

How would I determine if a sequence is true?
Lets say I have this code

```
int a = random.nextInt(10);
int b = random.nextInt(10);
int c = random.nextInt(10);
```

How would I use an if statement or a loop to determine if/when a = 1, b = 2, and c = 3 (or any combination of a,b, and c being only one number apart. Like 4,5,6 or 7,8,9) is in a sequence such as stated?

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise about what you want. What happens when (a=5, b=4, c=3) -- should that be true or false? What about (a=3, b=1, c=2)? You should give some more thought as to what the conditions are more precisely -- and that may then also give you a clue as to how to compute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the distance between the two numbers is equal to one:

```
if(b-a == 1 && c-b == 1)
```

Comment: From the OP's description, I think (5, 4, 3) should also evaluate to true, which this won't handle. I think (3, 1, 2) should be true, too. And I'm not sure about (5, 5, 5).

Comment: yes, basically anything that is in the sequence of 1,2,3 or 4,5,6 and so on and so forth. No 5,5,5's or 7,7,7's

Answer (score 0):

```
int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
boolean isSequence = Arrays.equals(IntStream.range(min, min+3).toArray(), new int[]{a,b,c});
```

Populate array as sequence (range) and compare with original values(as array)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like,

```
public static boolean checker() {
    // you can do this without worrying about overflow
    // because nextInt method generates a number btw 0(inclusive) and 10(exclusive)
    return (b-a == 1 && c-b == 1) || (b-a == -1 && c-b == -1);
    //            1, 2, 3         or          3, 2, 1
}
```